# C++ Operator (unsure of)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Is there a c++ operator that i could use for a for loop where it would add or subtract to variables based on whether one of the variables is less than or greater 0.
For instance

```
int a;
int b;
for(int i=0;i<some_number; i++)
  result = a +< b
  result = a-> b
```

Comment: Can you give some more specific examples of how this operator is supposed to work?

Comment: Are you looking for `abs` (absolute value)? See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/abs/

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can combine with the `?:` operator.

```
int a;
int b;
for(int i=0;i<some_number; i++)
  result = (a < b)? result+b:result-b;
```

That is if I understood your example correctly.

`->` is an existing dereference operator.

Operator `?:` is an equivalent to the `if...else` construct. If the statement before `?` evaluates to `true`, the statement right after the `?` gets executed, otherwise the statement after the `:` gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
result += a > 0 ? b : -b;
```

Note that this will subtract b if `a == 0`, which isn't quite what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but the [ternary operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14631/) is close.

```
for(int i=0;i<some_number; i++)
    result = (a > 0)?(a):(b);
```

This line will be equivalent to `result = a` when a is greater than 0, and `result = b` elsewise.

It could also be written as `result = a?a:b;`, but the longer form is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be any help?

```
result = a + (b*(a < b));
result = a - (b*(a > b));
```

Basically, `(a < b)` is converted into a boolean, which is basically either 1 (true) or 0 (false). `b` multiplied by 0 is of course zero, so nothing is added, and `b` multiplied by 1 is exactly `b`'s value.